# Understanding iPhone 5/6 resolution on image.xcassets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcasset

As the title says, I'm still confused to understand how image.xcassets handles the iPhone 5/6 images. Let me explain better:

[image: example]

This is my `MENU_EMPTY_LIST` file in image.xcassets. I've been looking for an answer here in stackoverflow and I found this:

- 1x images are for the original iPhone through the 3GS - 'standard' resolution devices (3.5" screens)
- 2x images are for the iPhone 4, 4S (3.5" Retina screens) and also **iPhone 6.**
- Retina 4 2x are for the iPhone 5 and 5s (4" Retina screens)
- 3x images are for the new iPhone 6+ (5.5" super-Retina [3x] screen)

This helped me a lot but my question is: what if the image set is a background (in short, an image covering all the screen)? How can I handle the different screen size? What do I have to put into the "2x" square? An iPhone 4/4S image or iPhone 6?

Answer (score 0):

only one problem is iPhone 4 and iPhone 6 taking same @2x images.

So, If you want to set perfect image for all the devices then you have to try following code :

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==480)
{
    login_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i4_login.png"];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568)
{
    login_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i5_login.png"];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==667)
{
    login_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i6_login.png"];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==736)
{
    login_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i6+_login.png"];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==1024)
{
    login_bg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_login.png"];
}
```

Comment: So I don't have to use image.xcassets in that case?

Comment: Yes! Thanks I forgot to answer :) I just was looking a way to organize the folders and files with this new method :)

Comment: This would be much nicer to read if it were switch((NSInteger)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)  ...long if/else/else chains are ugly

Comment: It's Work for you ? Please accept my answer @user3582537